# Create multi-select with typeahead in EpiServer

Tags: episerver

I need to build a component that essentially will allow editor to pick couple of users from the organization and then display that information on the page.
Information about users comes from an REST service endpoint, but that is not most critical at the moment.

The property should allow:

1. choose multiple values
2. allow typeahead (becasue organization can have thousands of users)

I have tried so far:

1. define the property as `IList<string>`, which gives me nice UI for editing, but doesn't have typeahead:

   `public virtual IList<string> Users { get; set; }`
2. created implementation for `ISelectionQuery` to provide typeahead and filtering for specified query, but it doesnt allow multiple values and overrides the UI and throws an error on save:

   ```cs
   [ServiceConfiguration(typeof(ISelectionQuery))]
   public class UserSelectionQuery : ISelectionQuery
   {
       private readonly SelectItem[] _items;

       public UserSelectionQuery()
       {
           _items = new[]
           {
               new SelectItem() {Text = String.Empty, Value = string.Empty},
               new SelectItem() {Text = "John Doe", Value = "john.doe@alloy.com"},
               new SelectItem() {Text = "Jane Doe", Value = "jane.doe@alloy.com"}

           };
       }

       public ISelectItem GetItemByValue(string value)
       {
           return _items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value.Equals(value));
       }



       public IEnumerable<ISelectItem> GetItems(string query)
       {
           return _items.Where(i => i.Text.Contains(query));
       }
   }
   ```

   Used it like so:

   ```cs
   [AutoSuggestSelection(typeof(UserSelectionQuery))]
   public virtual IList<string> Users { get; set; }
   ```

I'd like to keep it simple and leverage OOTB features as much as possible. I'm also open for suggestions how to workaround the issue.

Comment: Have you looked into the `SelectMany` attribute?

Comment: @TedNyberg: I did, but it renders checkboxes on the UI and it's not possible to filter it, therefore not really solving problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly sure you'll have to use a custom editor for your scenario